# How to dynamically set color properties of a button for Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I want to change a button's Foreground color every time I press the button and restore the color to original when I lift my finger.

How should I implement that?

I am trying with Key_down and Key_up events, using SolidColorBrush, but the SolidColorBrush doesn't accept "Color" as a parameter and reports error: "The name 'Color' does not exist in current context".

(The parameter list)
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you defining and setting the value of Color?  Please post your code in your question, pictures are harder to read.

Comment: Wait... what do you mean by setting the value of color? How do I do that?

Comment: You are using Color as a variable, that is why it is not being shown as an option in your dropdown, since you are using Windows Phone 8.1 you probably are want to use something like [`Windows.UI.Color`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.colors.aspx)

Comment: I added Windows.UI; namespace to the file and it has worked.

Comment: Glad you got it working, you really should go back to your first question and mark Walt's answer as what solved it. I am going to vote to close this as a duplicate of your first one.

Answer (score 0):

to set the color in the code in windows phone 8.1 RT try below.

```
(sender as Button).Foreground = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red)
```

Comment: Button rdbtn = sender as Button;
       rdbtn.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0));